# How to detect division by zero using std::error_code

Tags: c++, math, std, divide

I want to detect division by zero using std::error_code. Without the use of exceptions. How can I do that? Write some simple examples.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. We can help you with coding issues. However, we are not a code writing or homework service. You should write it yourself. P.s. `std::error_code` *is* an exception.

Comment: SO is not a "do work for me" site.

Comment: You cannot detect division by zero (which is Undefined Behaviour) *after* the fact. You have to write your code in a way where you detect *up front* that a division by zero *will* happen if you continue and then make the code do something that does then *not do* the operation that would divide by zero. In short; you must *avoid* doing it, you cannot reliably *detect* it having been done.

Comment: @ANurbaev the wording of the question makes it look very much like a cut and paste of a homework problem. You can probably fix this with a quick rewrite. Another problem with the question is is shows no signs of research effort. This could be an [X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If it is, it's too late for this question as it has been correctly answered. You should ask a new question focused on the problem that lead you to this problem.

Answer (score 4):

> I want to detect division by zero

Like this:

```
if(divisor != 0) {
    result = some_number / divisor;
} else {
    // error detected
}
```

> using std::error_code

You cannot detect errors with `std::error_code`. `std::error_code` can be used to report errors that you've detected.